# cannot start maximo due to error in ConfigDB

Tags: maximo

I get the error "ConfigDB and RestoreFromBackup actions must be complete before the Maximo server can start." on my systemOut.log file.

Can anyone please help me on how to ConfigDB so that I can start maximo server.

Comment: I see you have been opening new questions as you get more information instead of updating (or closing?) the old ones. The real question is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48290552/maximo-field-length-of-table-not-matching

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the Log directory where configdb.bat is located, you will see a seperate log file relating to the last failed configdb.bat action + a log relating to the restoration of any backup tables. This is where you will find details of your MAXIMO actual error\problem...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're on Windows...

1. Open a Command Prompt on your Administrative Workstation.
2. Use the `CD` command to get to `IBM\SMP\maximo\tools\maximo` on the appropriate drive and path.
3. Run `configdb.bat`.
4. Check for errors and handle them appropriately.
5. Close the Command Prompt.

You could run `configdb.bat` from File Explorer, but then the DOS window will close before you can see any errors in the output.

Comment: Thanks for the head start.

After running `configdb.bat` I get a whole bunch of following errors:
BMXAA6423W - The value for MAXPROP ** could not be cached. No value for the property was found.

And at the end of the cmd output I see
BMXAA6819I ConfigDB completed with errors
BMXAA6820I RestoreFromBackup completed without errors