# Maximo field length of table not matching

Tags: maximo

The **cmd log** of `configDB.dat` says "The row length of the table exceeded a limit of ...."

Is this the reason for my maxiomo server not starting up? How can I address this issue?
(screenshot of log attached below)

[image: first half of the log]

[image: remaining of the log]

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is the reason Maximo won't start. You need to shorten the requested width of the LOCATIONS table. If you have a backup, you should restore to it and use the UI to re-make your changes but make sure the sum of the lengths of the persistent attributes is less than 32677. If you don't have a backup, then you'll have to use SQL to figure out which attributes you want to shorten and then `update MAXATTRIBUTECFG set length = <desiredLength> where objectname = 'LOCATIONS' and attributename = '<desiredAttribute>'`. Then you can try to `configdb` again.

Answer (score 0):

The configdb.bat process implements the changes stored within various cfg tables as compared against the existing metadata tables (e.g. maxattributecfg versus maxattribute, maxobjectcfg versus maxobject etc).

You should be able to startup your server and access the Database Configuration application to see what changes are pending for the LOCATIONS object.

You will  then be able to use the remove configuration changes to abort the pending changes that are failing.

The reason the configdb process is failing is that the length of the total fields within the LOCATIONS object  (including you most recent changes) now exceeds the system table limit of 32,677 bytes.

If you need to add long text fields,  you should be using the maximo LONGALN datatype to generate a Long Description entry e.g. DESCRIPTION_LONGDESCRIPTION which by default is linked to DESCRIPTION within the LOCATIONS object.